# iFrame resize to content on page resize.

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that when loads sizes height according to content. When i resize the page, or with the same size window, descrease the width of the iframe, the content height increases accordingly. How do i get the iframe to stretch accordingly.

Comment: what code have you so far?

Comment: may be, keep the iframe in a <div>, and make the div's width and height in percentage(%).

Comment: use css and set it width to auto

Comment: @Sora Okay thanks. How do i access the iframe id from within the page content of the iframe. Setting to height to auto does not work.

Comment: Could you provide a small demo on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

This project on Github does what your after.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Without seeing your code I expect the issue is your using scrollHeight rather than offsetHeight.